# Calculator Layout in WPF

Tags: wpf, dockpanel

I have to design a calculator, but am working on the design first. The `=` button doesn't go into the space between the other buttons on the screen where I would like to place it. Here is a picture of what I have so far:

[Uploaded with imageshack.us http://imageshack.us/a/img843/7687/unbenannt22z.jpg](http://imageshack.us/a/img843/7687/unbenannt22z.jpg)

I used StackPanels to create my Main Panel. How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: please make your question more readable. As it currently stands it is difficult to tell what is it you are asking for

Comment: look at the photo it has to be like a calculator with out space between the buttons

Comment: Its done with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate in C#

Comment: You should definitely use a [Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx) for that layout.

Comment: Its a homework and we are not allowed to use a grid, and i dont know how to do this with a grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you arrange your buttons in a Grid rather than a collection of StackPanels, then you'd be able to put the Equals button in the next to last row of the grid, and set its Grid.RowSpan to 2 so that it would work out as you intended.

Comment: hmm thanks for this answer but it has to be in stackpanels -.-

Comment: If this is homework, and your instructor has mandated StackPanels, then i'll just give a hint that may solve your layout ... Think about negative margin... In truth, though, the Grid is the proper Panel for this layout

Comment: hmm it dont work with negativ margin, i tried everything, VerticalAlignment, Dockpanels etc. what should i do?